# Why do p-values for logistic regression coefficients not jibe with p-values for the differences in predicted probability based on those coefficients?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I am running a logistic regression based on a complex survey design. I want to know, for example, the probability of a black male from the 3rd income quintile going to jail vs. a white male from the same quintile going to jail, and I want to know if the difference in probabilities is statistically significant.

The problem I'm running into is that when I calculate the p-value for any given comparison, based on the `predict` function, it doesn't seem to line up with the p-values presented for each coefficient from the regression readout.

To simplify, here's the readout from a model without income as a variable:

```
svyglm(formula = jailedBinary ~ sex + race, data = data.w, family = "binomial", 
    design = addHealth)

Survey design:
svydesign(ids = ~data.w$CLUSTER2, data = data.w, weights = data.w$GSWGT4_2)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -1.9700     0.1412 -13.953  < 2e-16 ***
sexMale       1.3814     0.1208  11.433  < 2e-16 ***
raceWhite    -0.6185     0.1365  -4.532 1.31e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1.00666)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

My understanding is that, holding sex constant, the p-value for the difference in log odds between `raceBlack` and `raceWhite` is 1.31e-05.

Next I use the predict function to get a predicted probability and a confidence interval for each pairing of race and sex (see: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/):

```
newdata <- with(data.w, data.frame(sex = factor(rep(c("Female", "Male"),2), levels = c("Female", "Male")),
                                   race=factor(rep(c("Black", "White"), each=2), levels = c("Black", "White"))
                                   ))

newdata2 <- cbind(newdata, predict(noIncome, newdata = newdata, type = "link",
                                   se = TRUE))
newdata2 <- within(newdata2, {
  PredictedProb <- plogis(link)
  LL <- plogis(link - (1.96 * SE))
  UL <- plogis(link + (1.96 * SE))
})
```

The printout for `newdata2` looks like this:

```
sex      race       link         SE         UL         LL    PredictedProb
1 Female Black -1.9699868 0.14119141 0.15534870 0.09563260    0.12239031
2   Male Black -0.5886185 0.13753092 0.42090536 0.29771993    0.35695190
3 Female White -2.5884743 0.10725691 0.08484629 0.05739458    0.06988389
4   Male White -1.2071060 0.07436215 0.25705037 0.20540387    0.23021351
```

This seems pretty straightforward, as the `link` column is just adding the coefficients to the intercept in the cases where the variable level isn’t a part of the intercept. Then `PredictedProb` is just converting log odds to probability. (I don’t know where the `SE` comes from for each specific combination of levels, though.)

Next I write a (probably cumbersome) function that will let me calculate a standard error for the difference between any two predicted probabilities and then divide the difference in those means by that standard error to get a z statistic for calculating p-value (using the formula from here: http://www.bmj.com/content/343/bmj.d2304):

```
cisp <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  temp1 = (a-b)/(2*1.96)
  temp2 = (d-e)/(2*1.96)
  g = sqrt(temp1^2+temp2^2)
  h=(c-f)
  x=h-1.96*g
  y=h+1.96*g
  se=(y-x)/(2*1.96)
  zstat=abs(h/se)
  p=exp(-0.717*zstat - 0.416*zstat^2)

  output=list(h,x,y,p)

  return(output)
}
```

Now I plug in the predicted probabilities and confidence intervals (copy/paste the last from the last three columns of `newdata2`) for the two comparisons I want to make. First, black males to white males, then black females to white females:

```
cisp(0.42090536, 0.29771993, 0.35695190, 0.25705037, 0.20540387, 0.23021351)
cisp(0.15534870, 0.09563260, 0.12239031, 0.08484629, 0.05739458, 0.06988389)
```

In the first case, I get a p-value of 0.009, and in the second case, a p-value of 0.026. This seems right, but, again, it doesn’t match up to the p-value we got for `raceWhite` as a variable level, which is p < 0.000005. This doesn’t make sense to me. It seems like what I did was keep `sex` constant, `Male` in one case, `Female` in the other, and vary `race`, through all of the possibilities, by using the provided coefficients and the intercept. But none of the possible combinations returned a p-value close to the p-value of the raceWhite coefficient.

In this example, we have statistically significant results no matter which way we look at it. But in some cases, it’s the difference between p > 0.05 and p< 0.05. My questions (and hopefully they can be answered with the information provided) are:

1. Am I making a mistake in calculating the p-values in the predicted probability comparisons?
   and
2. If not, which way is better to interpret it? That, eg. `race` is significant at the p < 0.000005 level, or the p<0.01 levels for `Males`, and p < 0.05 level for `Females`?
3. And if anybody can explain to a beginner like me where that lower p-value for the coefficient itself comes from, that would also be very awesome.

Thank you so much.